play music automatically by C++ in ubuntu 22.04.5 with ROS2
I'm coding ROS to automatically play musics case by case in Ubuntu 22.04. In detail, purpose of code is noticing the status of robot by speaker. Robot is designed to follow target so if target is neutral play no sound, target is detected play music1, and target is lost play music2
int g_target_detecting_state = 0; // global variable to save status

void clusteringNode::timer_callback()
{
   // Determine status, ROS code 
}

void followingSoundPlay(void) // (const char* filename)
{
    sf::SoundBuffer go_buffer, stop_buffer;

    if (!go_buffer.loadFromFile("audio/music1.wav") || !stop_buffer.loadFromFile("audio/music2.wav"))
    {
        std::cerr << "load failed!";
    }

    sf::Sound go_sound, stop_sound;

    go_sound.setBuffer(go_buffer);
    stop_sound.setBuffer(stop_buffer);

    while(1)
    {
        if(g_target_detecting_state == 0)
        {
            go_sound.stop();
            stop_sound.stop();
        }
        else if(g_target_detecting_state == 1)
        {
            stop_sound.stop();
            go_sound.play();
        }
        else if(g_target_detecting_state == 2)
        {
            go_sound.stop();
            stop_sound.play();
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main(int nArgc,const char* pszArgv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(nArgc, pszArgv);

    auto node = std::make_shared<clusteringNode>();

    std::thread ros_thread([&](){
        rclcpp::spin(node);
    });
    std::thread play_thread(followingSoundPlay);

    if(ros_thread.joinable())
    ros_thread.join();
    if(play_thread.joinable())
    play_thread.join();

    rclcpp::shutdown();

    return 0;
}

This is my code in short. If you need more explain please let me know.
I tried crontab -e to run my code automatically when boot(I heard that systemd is quite fatal so I didn't try so far). Of course I make script and give permission 777.
I run the code manually it works with music, and crontab -e also work but only the music part didn't work. Is there any point I missed? If you find it please let me know
PS. thanks to read my question even thought my bad English.
One thing weird is I tried with 2 PC but one works and other one didn't. Is there any possibility that I installed Ubuntu wrong?

This seems to be more a question about using crontab and/or Ubuntu setup than about a specific programming problem. That would make it more a Super User question,

What audio backend is used? Perhaps when program run by cron, no pulseaudio server is running, or no permissions to audio device granted if user is not logged in. Did you add it to user's crontab or system crontab? What is log output from your program when it run by cron? Did you check if audio subsystem initialization succeeds? Side note: don't set permissions 0777 to script, it's security vulnerability.

@dimich Hi, I tried ALSA and SFML, and user added to user crontab.  I also guessing 'no pulseaudio server is running, or no permissions to audio device granted if user is not logged in' is problem but i don't know how to check it. Can you tell me the solution?

@chobo This question is specific for your OS and audio framework configuration, not a programming question.
